# Google Cal API returning incomplete Events Resource

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm using the `list` method from the Google Calendar API to get event data. The API successfully returns basic information about each event like `start`, `end`, `location`, and `attendees`, but it's missing fields like `guestsCanInviteOthers` and `guestsCanModify` that are listed on the [Events Resource Reference Page](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events).

Why doesn't the calendar API send these fields as well, and how can I modify my calls to the API to get these fields?

Comment: By default apis don't return all data. One has to set "setFields" value. For example in your case set the value as "items(attendees,end,guestsCanInviteOthers,guestsCanModify,location,start)" to check whether you get all values or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to expand on @Teyam's answer.

So you can get `guestsCanModify`, `guestsCanInviteOthers` and `guestsCanSeeOtherGuests` back from the [Events.list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events) call.

You simply need to include those fields into the `fields` parameter. So to get them back along with the event title (summary), you would pass this to `fields`.

```
items(summary,guestsCanInviteOthers,guestsCanSeeOtherGuests,guestsCanModify)
```

You need to leave out spaces in the string above. Be careful that when you use the `fields`, it will ONLY return the specified fields back instead of returning the default response plus what you specify.

There is one more caveat around the guests permissions. It will ONLY get returned when it is DIFFERENT from the default. So the default values according to the docs are:

```
guestsCanModify: false
guestsCanInviteOthers: true
guestsCanSeeOtherGuests: true
```

So if `guestsCanModify` is not included in your result, it's because it is `false` (the default value). You will only see it returned when it is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that in [Events](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events), there are certain properties that are not applicable to some methods and same goes with parameters (path parameters and optional query parameters) too.

As per checking, here are the possible reasons why doesn't the calendar API returned `guestsCanInviteOthers`:

- `guestsCanInviteOthers` is applicable in [Events: import](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/import) and [Events: insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) methods.
- From the list of parameters given in [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list), `guestsCanInviteOthers` and `guestsCanModify` were not included and are not applicable.

Now, to answer your question on how to modify calls to the API to get these fields:

- As far as I know and also based in the documentations, it is possible to get only the fields that are included in the [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) by adding the parameter name in the HTTP request.
- You may check each [method documentations](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#methods) to know the properties and parameters that can be returned in your requests.

I hope that helps.